# python: _winreg type name

Tags: python, winreg

Regarding Value Types: http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#value-types

How do I query `_winreg.REG_BINARY` for `'REG_BINARY'`?

I can do it manually with:

```
import _winreg
reg_type_str = {
    _winreg.REG_BINARY: 'REG_BINARY',
    _winreg.REG_DWORD: 'REG_DWORD',
    _winreg.REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN: 'REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN',
    _winreg.REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN: 'REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN',
    _winreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ: 'REG_EXPAND_SZ',
    _winreg.REG_LINK: 'REG_LINK',
    _winreg.REG_MULTI_SZ: 'REG_MULTI_SZ',
    _winreg.REG_NONE: 'REG_NONE',
    _winreg.REG_RESOURCE_LIST: 'REG_RESOURCE_LIST',
    _winreg.REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR: 'REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR',
    _winreg.REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST: 'REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST',
    _winreg.REG_SZ: 'REG_SZ',
}
reg_type_str.get(_winreg.REG_SZ)
```

Surely there's a better way?

### What I'm trying to do ...

Example Query:

```
reg_data, reg_type = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, reg_value)
log.debug("Query: %s [%d:%s]" % (reg_data, reg_type, reg_type_str.get(reg_type)))
```

I'm thinking I should be able to do something like this:

```
>>> for k, v in _winreg.__dict__:
...     if v == _winreg.REG_SZ:
...         print k

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#468>", line 1, in <module>
    for k, v in _winreg.__dict__:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Of course, that doesn't work, but even if it did this method would cause issues when used with _winreg:

```
>>> for v in _winreg.__dict__.itervalues():
...    if v == _winreg.REG_SZ:
...        print v

1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically get the name of a registry type from a registry type object?

Comment: More generally, what are you actually trying to do here? Why do you want to "query `_winreg.REG_BINARY`"?

Comment: Added "What I'm tying to do ..." to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that I need to do it using the manual method supplied in the original question.

The only way around this is if the _winreg developers supply a function for us.